# Function of 私に when someone else wants someone to do something

Tags: grammar, particles, particle-に

> 私の妻はこの古いよい帽子を私にすててほしいと思っている。

I understand this sentence, but when I dissect it, I realize I'm not sure why に is being used. Does anyone care to explain?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the site! I'm new, too. (For me it's more about old shoes than hats; when your feet get used to them, it is hard to throw them away no matter how much your wife is yelling...)

In general, the sentence was a bit clumsy, I think, but AFAIK the に　is used correctly. (=She wants **you** to be the person to throw it away). I don't know about your Japanese skills, so, allow me, we need to get used also to illogical structures, esp. when seen from the English point of view). I mean, I have still difficulties even to accept that AはB***に***勝った is OK...

Comment: Hey 'Tuomo', are you also a fellow Finn? I found this sentence on Kanshudo which uses native Japanese example sentences. I use these for anki reviews, but noticed that, although I understand the sentence, I am no exactly sure of why に is being used here. It might just be some sort of nuance that isn't important to grasp right now, but I want to be careful to not get the most out of my anki reviews.

Comment: Anki??? Anyway, forgot the latin version of "nimi on enne" (nomen es omen?). Interesting as an example sentence. The "に”　slightly emphasized you (or, specifically defined who she wants to throw away your old hat).

Comment: In these constructs に marks who will perform the action. Similarly with the causative.